# pytest cannot find a module when the tests are inside a sub directory of the project

Tags: pytest

I have a project

```
.
├── src
│   ├── constants.py
│   ├── __input__.py
│   └── main.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_main.py
```

where *main.py* imports a value from *constants.py*

When I run

```
python src/main.py
```

the output is as I expect

However, if I run *pytest* I get an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'constants'
```

The files are:

**constants.py**

```
HELLO = 'Hello'
```

**main.py**

```
from constants import HELLO

def main():
    print(HELLO)
    return HELLO

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**test_main.py**

```
from src.main import main

def test_main():
    assert main() == 'Hello'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about `from .constants import HELLO` ?

Comment: That's it - do you want to work up an answer?

Comment: But now python src/main.py throws an error: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28151907/3070181). It's hacky and I'm not totally happy with it, but it works. In my use case I have a relatively small program with a few imports, but a significant amount of testing.

**Main.py** becomes

```
from pathlib import Path

if __name__ == Path(__file__).stem:
    from constants import HELLO
else:
    from .constants import HELLO

def hello():
    print(HELLO)
    return HELLO


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

Now both

```
python main.py
```

and

```
pytest
```

work.

The reason they work is that if I run the program, *__name__ == "__main__"*.

But if I run pytest then *__name__ == "src.main"*

**Note** that in the configration described in the question you cannot have __init__.py in the root directory (i.e. the level above *src* and *tests*).

Answer (score 0):

When you run `pytest`, it's like that you are loading modules out of `src` dir, so when python faces `from constants ...`, it can't find `constants`, because we have two modules here: src and tests (and also installed modules).

So to fix that, you have two ways:

1- Relative import:

`from .constants import HELLO`

NOTE: In this way you are not able to run `python src/main.py`, because python does not know what is the parent module.

2- Module import properly:

`from src.constants import HELLO`

If you want to be able to run with both manually and pytest, you have two ways in that case too:

1- run `python -m src.main`

2- Use `try except` when importing, if got error, use the other import way

Comment: This fixes the test, but see my comment above. This does not work because when  I run main.py it  with .constants throws an error ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
 and if i try src.constants the error is ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Comment: I updated my answer for you @Psionman